# Unexpected token '{'. import call expects exactly one argument - when trying to import chart.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, chart.js, pug

I am creating a simple node.js app that uses chart.js for some visualisations but when trying to import and use Chart I am getting errors.

I used npm to install chart.js and served it to the client with:

```
app.use('/scripts', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/chart.js/dist')))
```

I am using pug as a rendering engine and have imported the scripts:

```
script(type="module" src="./scripts/chart.js")
script(src="/scripts/index.js")
```

Then in the index.js file when I try and import the chart module using:

```
import { Chart } from './chart.js/auto';
```

I get an error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'. import call expects exactly one argument.

Removing the curly braces doesn't work either.

I can see the chart.js scripts are included in the sources of the page but it will not load into the script I have tried omitting the import as I saw that inline scripts do not need this however that produces another error saying that it cannot find the variable Chart

Unsure what I am doing wrong, whether it be with serving the files or with the client-side import.

Comment: Rather than editing solved into your question, you should post an answer with the solution. You can view the answer you included in your question in the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74804384/revisions)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know I could answer my own question. Have updated that now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved

I used a different link in the script tag. Instead of `/chart.js` I used `/chart.umd.js`.

```
script(src="/scripts/chart.umd.js")
```

Then I was not required to use any-side import statement in the client side index.js file